# Scikit unknown label type

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've been trying to learn a bit of machine learning by importing some data from an SQL database.

However, I encountered the following problem:

> raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %s" % repr(ys)) ValueError:
>   Unknown label type: (array([-1634.4, -1534.2, -1497.8, ...,  1670.6, 
>   1733.6,  1835. ]),)

From what I read all of my "Y-values" should be integers (which they are), and the X-values should be floats.

So I am not able to figure out why this problem arises. Below is a small samlpe of the X-values:

> [-0.4984, 1.8591, -0.0885, 0.1343, -1.1943, -0.9636, -1.2658, 1.5753,
>   -0.4106, -0.82, -0.8298, -1.4705, -1.5656, 1.9643, -1.9277, 1.0525, 1.2654]

And below is a small part of the Y-values:

> [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
>   1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]

And this is the part of the code that isn't working:

```
train, test, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(od,
                                                          eldif,
                                                          test_size=0.33,
                                                          random_state=42)
gnb = GaussianNB()
model = gnb.fit(train, train_labels)
```

I appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you passing your X data as an array or as a dataframe? Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441857/unknown-label-type-sklearn
I think this can be fixed if you use .values()

Comment: It might be. But I am not sure how I should change my code (since the example you linked seems slightly different).  I guess I should change the following "model = gnb.fit(train, train_labels)" but to what exactly?

Comment: can you print the first elements for what you have for train and train_labels, maybe od and eldif are backwards?

Comment: If this is the issue, then you would need to change your last line:
model = gnb.fit(train.values, train_labels) BUT I just noticed you use the train_test_split from sklearn, it should already take care of this I think?

Comment: Train_labels = [-38.0, 368.79999999999995]. Train = [[1]
 [1]
 [0]]

Comment: "model = gnb.fit(train.values, train_labels) " this doesn't work. I get an error message "'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'"

Comment: I can't replicate the error here. Is there any way to share the code that leads to the error? Also, did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346550/valueerror-unknown-label-type-unknown ?

Comment: Don't know if you solved this but stumbled across it - looks like your train and train_labels are the wrong way round - is `od` definitely the features and `eldif` definitely the target?